# How to assign a Resource Array to a variable in Godot 4?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot-4, array

In Godot 3, you could do this:

```
export var (Array, Resource) test_variable
```

I tried to recreate this in Godot 4, but I could not figure out how. This is what I tried:

```
@export var test_variable : (Array, Resource)
```

It does not work. How could I accomplish this in Godot 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the answer to this question. The answer is simple:

```
@export var test_variable : Array[Resource]
```

You can do this to create an Array of any node type. Just put the node type within the square brackets of the Array class and that's it!